# How to override the Open button of Java SWT FileDialog class

Tags: java, swt

I want the file selction dialog to be popping up when i press a button.For this i am using org.eclipse.swt.widgets.FileDialog class and opening the dialog. By default there are two buttons "Open"(the button we press after selecting the file) and "Cancel" button.

I want the name on the button to change from "Open" to "Import".

Is it possible to override this button on FileDialog?

Answer (score 5):

SWT uses OS resources. The file dialog you see is the typical OS dialog for opening files.
You can't change the button's text without implementing your own dialog.

The only alternative to `Open` is `Save` by using the style bit:

```
SWT.SAVE
```

instead of

```
SWT.OPEN
```